# Python C-c C-c closes all other buffers

Tags: python, buffers

I am working with some python code and using `C-c C-c` to run one specific buffer while other python source files are open. As soon as it is launched, the other buffers are closed. This is highly irritating. I have to resplit the buffers (`C-x 3` etc) after every run.

I also use Emacs for LaTeX editing, and typsetting a document (`C-c C-a`) does not close all buffers. So, this is not an Emacs specific "feature". So, it is either python-mode that is perversely designed to do this, or my `.emacs` has some stuff in it that should not be there. Here are python relevant contents:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

Comment: Is `C-c C-c` bound to python-shell-send-buffer ?
Does same thing happen if you choose "Python" from the menu bar then "Eval Buffer"

Comment: Since you suspect that it is something in init files that causes this, have you tried this when running emacs as `emacs -Q` so it doesn't read the init files?